# Asp net core обработка 404

Tags: asp.net-core

Всем доброго времени суток!

Возник вопрос следующего характера: в asp net core хочу узнать url из-за которого упала 404-я ошибка.

Как можно это сделать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Надо использовать:

```
UseStatusCodePages(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<StatusCodeContext, Task> handler)
```